# Dreamweaver Syntax Highlight (Php, Html)

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-highlighting, dreamweaver, cc

I have just started using Dreamweaver CC, been using notepad++ previously. When I write code in Notepad ++, such as php, in notepad++, if I highlight an opening delimiter, it would automatically highlight the closing corresponding tag. Can someone explain to me how to do this in Dreamweaver CC, it is not there by default. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Check for balanced parentheses, braces, or square brackets

```
Open the document in Code view.
Place the insertion point in the code you want to check.
Select Edit > Balance Braces.

All of the code between the enclosing parentheses, braces, or square brackets is selected. Choosing Edit > Balance Braces again selects all of the code inside the parentheses, braces, or square brackets that enclose the new selection.
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WSc78c5058ca073340dcda9110b1f693f21-7ba2a.html